Sandwiching the Lp norm sequence of random variable
Let X be a random variable with $\Vert X\Vert_p = E[\vert X\vert^p]^{1/p}<\infty$ for all $p\geq 1$.
Assume for some fixed $r$, and for all $q,s$ satisfying $1\leq q < r < s$,
$$\lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{\Vert X\Vert_p}{p^{1/q}}=0$$
and
$$\limsup_{p\to\infty} \frac{\Vert X\Vert_p}{p^{1/s}}=\infty$$
Does this imply that there is some $K>0$ such that
$$\limsup_{p\to\infty} \frac{\Vert X\Vert_p}{p^{1/r}}=K$$

Just my opinion, but I think it would be easier for the reader to write that, for every $p \geq 1$ and $1 \leq q < r < s$, $$\lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{\Vert X\Vert_p}{p^{1/q}}=0$$ and $$\limsup_{p\to\infty} \frac{\Vert X\Vert_p}{p^{1/s}}=\infty$$ Your question then essentially becomes: does there exist at least one $r$ between $q$ and $s$ such that your $\limsup$ is bounded and not equal to $0$?

Thanks for the suggestion, I agree and have edited the question accordingly.

@mhdadk yes that is the correct interpretation. My intuition is that there is exactly one such r.

I'm not sure if this helps, but you could define the function $L : [1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ as $$L(z) = \limsup_{p\to\infty} \frac{\Vert X\Vert_p}{p^{1/z}}$$ If you then show that $L$ is continuous on some interval $[a,b]$, where $a \geq 1$ and $b < \infty$, then by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a $K > 0$ such that $L(z) = K$ for some $z \in [a,b]$.

@mhdadk $L$ here is clearly a function that goes from $0$ to $\infty$ in "one jump" at $z = r$, which is impossible for a continuous function...

@BrunoB Not sure I follow. It is given in the question that $q < s$, $L(q) = 0$, and $L(s) = \infty$. Because $q < s$, then why can't $L(z)$ be continuous in the interval $[a,b]$, where $a \geq q$ and $b \leq s$?

@mhdadk No, it's a fixed $r$ for which $L(q) = 0$ for all $q < r$ and $L(s) = \infty$ for all $s > r$, which only leaves the value at $r$ unknown.

@BrunoB Ahh, I see. I misunderstood the question then. Thanks.

The claim is false. Here is an explicit counterexample.
Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with density given by
$$p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}C_{3/2+1/2k} \exp\left ( -x^{3/2+1/2k} \right )$$
where
$$C_\alpha = \left ( \int_0^\infty \exp(-x^{\alpha})dx \right )^{-1}.$$
This ensures that the expression above is a genuine density since it is non-negative and integrates to 1.
I will show below that
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/q}} = 0$$
for all $1 \leq q < 3/2$ and
$$\limsup_{p\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/s}} = +\infty$$
for all $s > 3/2$. This means the value of $r$ must be $r = 3/2$ if it were to exist.
Finally I will show that
$$\limsup_{p\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/(3/2)}} = 0$$
which implies that the $X$ chosen fails to have the property you are looking for.

Intuition
The main trick in this scheme is to observe if $Z_\alpha$ is a random variable pdf $C_\alpha e^{-z^\alpha}$ then
$$\|Z_\alpha\|_p \approx p^{1/\alpha}$$
or by raising things to the $p$'th power
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_\alpha^p] \approx p^{p/\alpha}$$
From this it follows that
$$\mathbb{E}[X^p] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \mathbb{E}[Z_{3/2+1/2k}^p] \approx \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)}.$$
Taking $p$'th roots and dividing by $p^{1/q}$ gives
$$\frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/q}} \approx \left ( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p}\frac{1}{p^{1/q}} = \left ( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k) - p/q} \right )^{1/p}$$
Taking the limit as $p \rightarrow \infty$ for different values of $q$ will show the result.

Making this all rigorous is hairy
Step 0: Estimating $C_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in [1,2]$
This step is relatively easy but it's important to check that these constants are not going to cause problems. For $\alpha \in [1,2]$ we have
\begin{align}
   C_\alpha^{-1} 
   &= \int_0^\infty \exp^{-x^\alpha} dx \\
   &\leq 1 + \int_1^\infty \exp^{-x^\alpha} dx \\
   &\leq 1 + \int_1^\infty \exp^{-x} dx < 1.5
\end{align}
where the first inequality is because $\exp(-x^{\alpha}) \leq \exp(0) = 1$ and the second step is because when $x \geq 1$ it holds that $-x^{\alpha} < -x$ because $\alpha \geq 1$. The last inequality can be numerically verified.
For the reverse inequality
\begin{align}
    C_\alpha^{-1} 
    &= \int_0^\infty \exp^{-x^\alpha} dx \\
    &\geq \int_1^\infty \exp^{-x^\alpha} dx \\
    &\geq \int_1^\infty \exp^{-x^2} dx > 1/10
\end{align}
which uses similar ideas and a numerical bound at the end. Ultimately this shows that
$$ 2/3 < C_\alpha < 10$$
This is good enough to ensure that the $C_\alpha$ values really do not matter in this probably because they are multiplying by a positive constant that is bounded away from zero and bounded above.
Step 1: Bounds on $\mathbb{E}[Z_\alpha^p]$
Below it is established that for $p \geq 4$ and $\alpha \in (3/2,2]$ that there exist absolute constants $0 < a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2$ with $a_1 < 1 < a_2$ such that
$$c_1(a_1p)^{p/\alpha} \leq \mathbb{E}[Z_\alpha^p] \leq c_2(a_2p)^{p/\alpha}.$$
The arguments below are quite tedious so please skip feel free to skip them.
We can explicitly calculate
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}[Z_\alpha^p] 
   &= \int_0^\infty z^p C_\alpha e^{-z^\alpha} dz \\
   &= C_\alpha\int_0^\infty (u^{1/\alpha})^p e^{-(u^{1/\alpha})^\alpha} \frac{1}{\alpha} u^{1/\alpha - 1} du \\
   &= C_\alpha\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty u^{p/\alpha + 1/\alpha - 1} e^{-u} du \\
   &= \frac{C_\alpha}{\alpha} \Gamma\left ( \frac{p+1}{\alpha} \right )
\end{align}
where we have used the change of variable $u = z^{1/\alpha}$ and the definition of the $\Gamma$ function.
Note here that the leading term satisfies for all $p \geq 1$ and $\alpha \in [3/2,2]$ the bounds
$$ \frac{1}{3} < \frac{C_\alpha}{\alpha}  < 10$$
which follows from Step 0 and the fact that $\alpha \in (3/2,2]$. This shows that this term is also innocuous.
The real challenge is to estimate $\Gamma\left ( \frac{p+1}{\alpha} \right )$. To start we have
\begin{align}
   \Gamma\left ( \frac{p+1}{\alpha} \right )
   &= \left ( \Gamma\left ( \frac{p+1}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} \right )^{p/\alpha} 
\end{align}
The game is now to control the inner term. For $p \geq 4 \geq 2\alpha$ we have
\begin{align}
    \Gamma\left ( \frac{p+1}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} > \Gamma\left ( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} \geq \frac{p}{4\alpha} \geq \frac{p}{8}
\end{align}
which uses the fact (which I won't prove here) that for $t \geq 2$
$$\Gamma(t)^{1/t} \geq \frac{t}{4}.$$
We also have
\begin{align}
    \Gamma\left ( \frac{p+1}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} 
    &< \Gamma\left ( \frac{p}{\alpha} + 1\right )^{\alpha/p} \\
    &= \Gamma\left ( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} \left ( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} \\
    &\leq \left ( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right ) \left ( \frac{p}{\alpha} \right )^{\alpha/p} \\
    &\leq p ((p)^{1/p})^{\alpha} \alpha^{\alpha / p} \\
    &\leq p e^\alpha \alpha^{\alpha/p} \\
    &\leq p 4e^2 
\end{align}
which uses the property of the Gamma function $\Gamma(t+1) = t\Gamma(t)$ and also the inequality valid for $t \geq 2$ (which I also won't prove)
$$\Gamma(t)^{1/t} \leq t$$.
Combining the arguments above we have shown for $\alpha \in (3/2,2]$ and $p \geq 4$ that
$$\frac{1}{3}\left ( \frac{p}{4}\right )^{p/\alpha}\geq \mathbb{E}[Z_\alpha^p] \leq 10\cdot(4e^2p)^{p/\alpha}$$
which completes the step with the specified constants explicitly.
Step 2. Summing things up
This step is a bit easier. We have by the definition of $X$ that
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[X^p] 
    &= \int x^p \left ( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}C_{3/2+1/2k} \exp\left ( -x^{3/2+1/2k} \right ) \right ) dx \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \int x^pC_{3/2+1/2k} \exp\left ( -x^{3/2+1/2k} \right ) dx \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \mathbb{E}[Z_{3/2+1/2k}^p].
\end{align}
Using the upper and lower bounds from the previous step shows for $p \geq 4$
\begin{align}
    \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} c_1(a_2p)^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \leq \mathbb{E}[X^p] \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} c_2(a_2p)^{p/(3/2+1/2k)}
\end{align}
Step 3: Moments and Inequalities
Using the last step we have
\begin{align}
    \|X\|_p 
    &\leq \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} c_2(a_2p)^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &\leq \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} c_2(p)^{p/(3/2+1/2k)a_2^p} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &= a_2c_2 \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p}
\end{align}
where we have used that $a_2 > 1$.
Similarly we have
\begin{align}
    \|X\|_p 
    &\geq \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} c_1(a_1p)^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &\geq \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} c_2(p)^{p/(3/2+1/2k)a_1^{2p}} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &= a_1^2c_2 \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p}
\end{align}
where we have used $c_2 < 1$.
Step 4: Completing the argument
Since $a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2$ are absolute constants they won't effect the convergence to zero or infinity. I'm going to ignore them here and write $\propto$ to mean equality up to these absolute constants.
Now that we have everything in place, let's start concluding the argument. Let $1 \leq q < 3/2$. Let $\epsilon = 3/2 - q > 0$. We have by the last step
\begin{align}
   \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/q}} 
   &\propto \frac{1}{p^{1/q}} \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p} \\
   &= \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k) - p/q} \right )^{1/p} \\
   &\leq \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2) - p/q} \right )^{1/p} \\
   &= p^{(q - 3/2)/(3q/2)} = p^{-\epsilon/(3q/2)} 
\end{align}
and taking the limit as $p \rightarrow \infty$ shows that
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/q}}  = 0.$$
For the upper bound let $s > 3/2$ and let $k_*$ be large enough that $\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2k} < s$ then again starting with the previous step we have
\begin{align}
    \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/r}} 
    &\propto \frac{1}{p^{1/s}} \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &\geq \frac{1}{p^{1/s}} \left ( \frac{1}{2^{k_*}} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k_*)} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2^{k_*/p}}p^{1/(3/2+1/2k_*) - 1/s}
\end{align}
Since $(3/2+1/2k_*) < s$ the exponent in the last expression is strictly positive. Also, $2^{-k_*/p} \rightarrow 2^0 = 1$ so there is no issue there. This shows that
$$\limsup \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/s}} = +\infty.$$
Finally we conclude by checking the case where $r=3/2$. In this case we have by the previous step and Jensen's inequality (and the concavity of $x^{1/p}$ for $p \geq 1$) that
\begin{align}
   0\leq \frac{\|X\|_p}{p^{1/r}} 
    &\propto \frac{1}{p^{1/r}} \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{p/(3/2+1/2k)} \right )^{1/p} \\
    &\leq \frac{1}{p^{1/r}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{1/(3/2+1/2k)} \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{1/(3/2+1/2k) - 1/r}
\end{align}
Taking the limit as $p \rightarrow \infty$ gives
\begin{align}
   \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} p^{1/(3/2+1/2k) - 1/r}
   &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{2^k} p^{1/(3/2+1/2k) - 1/r} \\
   &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 0 = 0
\end{align}
The fact that the inner limit converges to zero is because for any $k \geq 1$ it holds that $1/(3/2+1/2k) - 1/(3/2) < 0$. The exchange of the limit and the sum is justified by Tannery's theorem. This establishes that the sequence has a limit and that the limit must be 0 (which implies that the $\limsup$ must also be zero). This completes the counterexample

Debrief
The main things that are important to know are that

a density like $e^{-z^{\alpha}}$ implies moments like $p^{1/\alpha}$.

Having a density which decays like $e^{-z^{r}}$ but not quite that speed is what causes an issue.

This probably works with the density
$$\exp(-x^{3/2 + \min(1/x, 1/2)})$$
because this tail gets close to $e^{-x^{3/2}}$ but never quite gets there. The calculations are probably terrible though.



A note on where this idea came from
The main idea is that as $x$ ranges from 0 to $\infty$ each $k$ term in the summation
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} C_{3/2+1/2k}\exp(-x^{3/2 + 1/2k})$$
will at some point be essentially the largest term in the summation. It's not something that has a nice formula, but you can plot the terms (best if done in log-scale, and ignoring the $C$ term) and see that as $x$ grows each $k$ term is the maximum in the sum for at least a little while.
What that means is, at least for a small interval $X$ essentially "looks like" something with density $e^{-x^{3/2 + 1/2k}}$ and the moments of this distribution act like $p^{1/(3/2 + 1/2k)}$.
From here I think it's pretty straightforward to see that the behavior above and below $r=3/2$ is what is expected. The only subtle point is what happens at $r=3/2$. This is where the fact that each term is strictly more concentrated than $e^{-x^{3/2}}$ is useful since when we move the limit into the sum each term will tend to zero.
The other fact that is important, but not well known, is that $e^{-x^\alpha}$ has moments like $p^{1/\alpha}$. This has much more well known special cases when $\alpha = 1$ or 2. A good reference for this is Chapter 2 of this book, especially the subsection on "Orlicz norms."
I will say that the choice of $r=3/2$ is arbitrary. The example can be adjusted to use any $r \geq 1$.

Could you possibly elaborate on how you came up with the pdf for $X$ in the first place? I am in complete awe of how someone thought of a very weird-looking (but appropriate!) pdf.

I've just added a short comment on the main ideas that I had in mind when cooking up this unusual random variable.

Thank you for this detailed response! I am going to accept it but it may take some time for me to fully process.
